# Modelling data with suitable kernel function

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, svm, kernel-density

I would like to ask for your information what kernel type or kernels combination would fit to this data on the figure below.

I used kernel ridge module from scikit-learn with this parameters:

```
clf = KernelRidge(kernel='rbf',gamma=0.01,alpha= 14.0)
```

Model with this kernel is given on the figure below.

I need some kernel that would be more flat on the top between 06:00 and 15:00.

Every point on the figure represent hourly value starting from 00:00:00 till 23:59:59.

Do you have some suggestions what kernel would fit better the date or maybe some combination of kernels?

Thanks!

[Figure of fitting the actual data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7o0I.png)

Comment: I think it's pretty accurate - you don't wan't to overfit the model (just my opinion)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It seems MLPRegressor gives better result, rmse  is 57, and with kernels 87.